# How Can I prove the three statements are equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, quotient-spaces

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map. Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> (a)$Y$ is an Hausdorff space,
>
> (b)$f$ is closed map,
>
> (c)The set $\lbrace (x_1,x_2) \in X\times X:f(x_1)=f(x_2) \rbrace$ is closed in $X\times X$

My attempt at solution:

** $(a\Rightarrow b)$ **

Let $A\subset X$ is closed set in $X$. Since $X$ is compact. $A$ is compact in $X$. As f is continuous $f(A)$ is compact. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff $f(A)$ closed. Then we obtain f is closed map.

** $(a\Rightarrow c)$**

Let
$\Delta = \lbrace (x_1,x_2) \in X\times X:f(x_1)=f(x_2) \rbrace $,

$(a,b )\in X\times X \setminus \Delta$.
Then $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff.

There is neighbourhood U,V such that $f(a) \in U$ $f(b) \in V$,

$U\cap V= \emptyset$

$a \in f^{-1}(U)$,$b \in f^{-1}(V)$

$f^{-1}(U)$, $ f^{-1}(V)$ are open in X since f is continuous.

Then $f^{-1}(U) \times f^{-1}(V)$ open in $X\times X$

Claim : $f^{-1}(U) \times f^{-1}(V)\cap A = \emptyset$,

Let $(x,y) \in f^{-1}(U) \times f^{-1}(V)$,

Then  $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ $y \in f^{-1}(V)$,

$f(x) \in U$, $f(y) \in V$,
$(x,y) \in A $ , $f(x)=f(y)$,

$U \cap V= \emptyset$

It is a contradiction. Then

$(a,b) \in  f^{-1}(U) \times f^{-1}(V) \subset X \times X \setminus \Delta$

$ X \times X \setminus \Delta$ is open. $\Delta$ is closed.

** $(c\Rightarrow a)$**

Let $\Delta$ is closed. Then $ X \times X \setminus \Delta$ is open. Let $(a,b) \in  X \times X \setminus \Delta$,  $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Since $ X \times X \setminus \Delta$ is open there is open neighbourhood $U \times V$ of $(a,b)$

$(a,b) \in U \times V \subset X \times X \setminus \Delta $

$U \times V \cap \Delta= \emptyset$...(*)

$f(a), f(b)\in Y$, $f(a) \neq f(b)$

$a \in U$,$f(a) \in f(U)$,
$b \in V$, $f(b) \in f(V)$

$f(U),f(V)$ are open since $f$ is quotient.

Claim: $f(U)\cap f(V)= \emptyset$

Let $x \in f(U)\cap f(V)$, $x \in f(U)$,$f^{-1}(x) \in U$ $x \in f(V)$, $f^{-1}(x) \in V$

$f^{-1}(x) \in U \cap V$, $U \times V \cap \Delta \neq \emptyset$.

It is contradiction with (*).Then distinct points in $Y$, have disjoint neighbourhoods.

*I must prove $(a\Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c \Rightarrow a)$ But I couldn't $b \Rightarrow c$ or $c \Rightarrow b$*

Comment: Is there any question you want to ask?

Comment: Can I use $(a \Leftrightarrow b)$, $a\Leftrightarrow c$ ?

Comment: You already have $a\Leftrightarrow c$ and $a\Rightarrow b$, so it will be enough to show $b\Rightarrow a$.

Comment: I tried to show $b\Rightarrow a$ but I couldn't.

Comment: if Y Hausdorf, single point closed. But inverse implication is not valid.

Comment: İf we show that single point closed we obtain Y is $T_1$. It may not $T_2$

Comment: Your answer seems true. Why did you remove it?

Comment: It had a small problem, which is fixed in the new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show $b\Rightarrow a$.

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, single points in $X$ are closed subsets. Since $f$ is closed and onto, for every $p\in Y$ there is $a\in X$ with $f(a)=p$, thus single points in $Y$ are also closed. Now let $p,q\in Y$, $p\neq q$, so the two subsets $f^{-1}(p),f^{-1}(q)$ are disjoint and closed in $X$. $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, thus normal, so there are two disjoint open $U,V\subset X$, with $f^{-1}(p)\subset U,f^{-1}(q)\subset V$. Note that $X\setminus U,X\setminus V$ are closed, and their union is the whole of $X$. Since $f$ is closed and onto, the subsets $f(X\setminus U),f(X\setminus V)$ are closed in $Y$, and their union is the whole of $Y$. Also, by construction, $p\not\in f(X\setminus U),q\not\in f(X\setminus V)$, and it follows that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Greats! Thanks.